# how to change the position of search box in front end?

Tags: magento2, css, phtml, php-7, js-css

I am trying to extend the Header (logo, search box and cart), but those files are the different location. I don't know how to adjust those. Could you please suggest me on this.
[image]

Comment: What you mean by extending the header? where you want to keep the search box? please share the screenshots so that it will be more visible to us.

Comment: i want to change the position of search box to the center of the page can u help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In your Custom/Theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml                                         


<move element="top.search" destination="header.panel" before="minicart" />
```

Comment: <move element="top.search" destination="header.panel" before="minicart" />

Comment: i didnt find this command

Comment: You have to add in your default.xml file

Comment: sorry no change sir

Comment: <move element="top.search" destination="header-wrapper" before="minicart" />

Comment: sorry no change sir

Comment: Have you cleared cache and checked??

Comment: yes sir but not working

Answer (score 1):

You can use margin-right in CSS as 35% or according to your need.

In your custom LESS File, Put this below Code :

.block-search{
margin-right: 35%;
}